# Number of Rows MVC Contrib Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Contrib Grid for ASP.NET MVC and I was wondering if there is a way to get the number of rows to be output from the grid renderer?  I'm trying to not add stuff from the renderer if there are no rows that are going to be shown.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it is baisically using the DataSource which is defined in the grid renderer and getting the count.  So DataSource.Count().

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows is the same as the number of records in your underlying data source.

Comment: and how do you get to that data from the renderer?

Comment: What are you using for a data source?